# Highcharts lang options for accessibility and screen readers

Tags: highcharts

I'm discovering Highcharts and its accessibility features. I'm translating a few keywords from English to French. However, for two sentences I can't find what's the property inside the lang object :

"**List of** {num} **items**"

"**List end**"

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Hi @Dominique Nauroy, Could you show the context where the text is used? You can use this simple example as a base to start: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, it's hard to display what a screen reader says, but when you enter the chart with the keyboard, the voice assistant tells the chart title, the chart type, the description, then other things like "View as table". These elements can be translated. For instance : 
accessibility: {
table: {
                viewAsDataTableButtonText: "Afficher en tableau"
            }
}

Before entering the annotations, we have a text saying "List of 1 items" (in my case I only have 1 annotation), then the annotation is read, then "List end". I can't find out how to translate these sentences.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I couldn't reproduce the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w8hgupy3/ but this is probably not directly related to Highcharts. Here you can find a similar question: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16985 - 'List of' is used by a screen reader if elements are in `<ul role="list">`.